# What is this command doing? (PowerShell $?)

Tags: powershell

Anyone have any idea what this IF command is doing?

```
Connect-SPConfigurationDatabase -DatabaseName "$configDB" -Passphrase $secPhrase -DatabaseServer "$dbServer" -DatabaseCredentials $dbcreds -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    If (-not $?)
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor White " - No existing farm found.`n - Creating config database `"$configDB`"..." }
```

I'm speculating it's an alternative to :

```
 Try { Do-Something -ea Stop }
 Catch { Write-host $_ }
```

but it's just that, speculation.
I've never seen anything like this before and it's not showing up just the once in a script I'm inheriting.  It's throwing me right off!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$?` is an automatic variable for the error status of the last executed command. See [`Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6).

> Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.

Comment: You're a legend. Thanks. Googling "$?" got me know where. That link is being saved to favourites.

Comment: Another nice list to bookmark: http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/powershell-specialcharactersandtokens

Comment: See also `$lastexitcode` for external commands.  Also `$error | select *`.